# How can I map multiple contexts inside the save server.xml in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I'm running tomcat 8.5 from eclipse and I have context.xml inside METAINF folder,
the content of this file is copied automatically to conf/server.xml on tomcat
runtime.

What I want to do id to let tomcat copy another context to the server.xml on runtime. The reason is that I need the second context to have path to images so
I can access them from outside the app. (from an angualr app in my case).

I tried to add another context tag to the context.xml, here is the complete
context xml:

```
<Context path="/test" docBase="C:\eclipse\workspace\myproj\test"
        debug="5" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">

<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" 
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              username="root" 
              password="simba"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/my_db?autoReconnect=true"              
              testOnBorrow="true"
              removeAbandoned="true"              
              logAbandoned="true"
              maxWait="60"
              maxActive="10" 
              maxIdle="4"/>              
</Context>

<Context path="/images" docBase="C:\Users\john\Documents\images"
        debug="5" reloadable="true" crossContext="true"> 

</Context>
```

and I'm getting error that only 1 allowed or more preciously:

```
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

I also try to create another file with different name but the content is not copied.
Any idea where to add/change the configuration to make it work ?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks to be an XML parsing exception, please post any stack trace you may have received, that would help. In addition, please post your complete context.xml. You seem to have added another 'Context' element, a document can have only one document element. Please post the complete XML as is, that would clear it up.

Comment: Then why were you trying to add another document element :), why not make another WAR file and deploy, after all, from what I see, they are different contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot place more than one 'Context' element is a context.xml file of Tomcat, it violates the wellformedness constraint; an XML document can only have one document element. What you are trying to do makes the context.xml file have more than one document element. Refer [Tomcat 9 Documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html). In the section 'Defining the Context', it provides the places you could define a context (note, it is not advisable to place Context elements in server.xml).

Comment: Thanks, but I understand that only 1 context allowed. I'm trying to get a solution.